# How do I fade out text when scroll to a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want add fade out to my footer text when click on scroll to footer div

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/JpsjX/

So here, when I click `Scroll to footer` link and I want add some animation on text `I want to Fade Out This Text`

Let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? : http://jsfiddle.net/JpsjX/1/

Modifying your `animate()` function with a callback will do it.

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 500, function(){
     $("#footer").fadeOut('slow');
});
```